# Wordpress rewrite_rule based on subdomain

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Is it possible to create rewrite_rules based on subdomain in Wordpress?

For example

se.domain.eu/page/cat/ = Results in page id 1 
dk.domain.eu/page/cat/ = Results in page id 2